# My question was closed as "opinion-based" despite not being opinion-based

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

My question [Why do SSDs tend to fail much more suddenly than HDDs?](https://superuser.com/q/1694872/890474) was closed by a mod as "opinion-based", despite being in no way opinion-based.  It asks for factual reasons why SSDs tend to fail more suddenly than HDDs despite the presence of a number of factors that would tend to tilt the balance in the opposite direction; this is an objective question that would attract solid, factual answers were it to be reopened.<sup>1</sup>

Honestly, I can't see a single way in which my question could reasonably be construed as being "opinion-based", certainly no more than [this well-received question about CPU failures](https://superuser.com/q/314337/890474).

As my question was closed under invalid premises, I'm requesting that the question be reopened.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Indeed, an answer [was in the process of being typed up](https://superuser.com/questions/1694872/why-do-ssds-tend-to-fail-much-more-suddenly-than-hdds#comment2606304_1694872) when a mod jumped in and shut down the question!

Comment: "It asks for factual reasons why SSDs tend to fail more suddenly than HDDs" - you provide no evidence for this assertion

Comment: @DavidPostill: This "assertion", as you put it, is what is taught in schools and is common knowledge among people who work with computer hardware where SSDs are concerned.

Comment: You mean "old schools", since nowadays SSDs last as long or longer than HDDs. As your title is already wrong, the rest is left to people's opinions based on their experiences.

Comment: Even if the queston is opinion based, I have an answer that is not.  The question should not have been closed.

Comment: There seems to be some contention that the question is "wrong." Such questions can be just as helpful as any other because misconceptions and outdated perceptions are often widely held and in need of updating or correction. Surely an answer for this question can do that by explaining how old drives failed. An excellent answer would also point out that how new drives fail differently. There are factual answers to this question, and I think answers should be judged on their own merit.

Comment: @DavidPostil What does that have to do with being closed as "opinion-based"? It's still a factual claim. Even if it the factual claim was untrue, that does not turn it into an opinion. An opinion is something that cannot entirely be answered with facts alone. This question can be, even if one answer is "modern SSDs don't fail more quickly than SSDs." Though, frankly, there is a much better answer than that. It has to do with write limits. If modern SSDs do last as long as hard drives, it's because of mitigation strategies. Flash memory does degrade faster than mechanical disks on its own.

Comment: Was the question title changed after the comments were made ? All the comments seem to address a supposed claim that SSDs fail faster/earlier than HDDs, whereas the question as it looks now is about SSDs failing *suddenly* instead of over the span of a week or two, which seems to be a completely different (and not even really related) question